# Same functions, different random results - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, random

Let's suppose i have an array of words

JS

```
var fruit = [banana, apple, watermelon, mango];

function loadFruit() {
    var randomFruit = fruit[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruit.length)];
    $('.divLoadFruit').parent('div').html(randomFruit);
};
```

I need to trigger function on click of the middle word of the sentence, to obtain different random matches

HTML

```
"You need to eat <a class="divLoadFruit" href='javascript: loadFruit();'>just_some_fruit</a>: it is good for your health."

"My son doesn´t like <a class="divLoadFruit" href='javascript: loadFruit();'>another_fruit_here</a>."
```

When you click on one of the links, it triggers the same function (obviously) but gets me the same fruit in that spaces. Is there any way to make it random without repeating?

Comment: Random without repeating? That's not truly random then. Each time your "randomly" select an item, you have the same odds of of getting the same item again

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How to efficiently randomly select array item without repeats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891173/javascript-how-to-efficiently-randomly-select-array-item-without-repeats)

Comment: Please fix your HTML: where is the `divLoadFruit` class applied?

Comment: the problem is that you use jQuery and `$('.divLoadFruit').parent('div')` targets multiple destinations - you need to rethink, perhaps `loadFruit(this)` to pass in the clicked `<a>` element to the function - it's not clear from your HTML what is targetted by your jQuery either

Answer (score 1):

Considering you click on the anchor tag and get a random fruit, the following code will work.

```js
var fruit = ['banana', 'apple', 'watermelon', 'mango'];

function loadFruit(id) {
    var randomFruit = fruit[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruit.length)];
document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = randomFruit;
};
```

```html
You need to eat <a id='just_some_fruit' href='javascript: loadFruit("just_some_fruit");'>just_some_fruit</a>: it is good for your health.

My son doesn´t like <a id='another_fruit_here' href='javascript: loadFruit("another_fruit_here");'>another_fruit_here</a>.
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is an approach with jquery.**

```js
var fruit = ["banana", "apple", "watermelon", "mango"];

function loadFruit(caller) {
  var randomFruit = fruit[Math.floor(Math.random() * fruit.length)];
  $(caller).html(randomFruit);
};

$('a').click(function() {
  loadFruit(this);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  "You need to eat <a href='#'>just_some_fruit</a>: it is good for your health." "My son doesn´t like <a href='#'>another_fruit_here</a>."
</div>
```

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: This is it, Thank you!