# returning a function that uses a var declared in the parent function

Tags: javascript, function, random, scope

this is a function that chooses items randomly from a given array until all are taken and only then repeating

i actually copied the code from a post because i couldn't understand how the variable copy's scope works .

PS : here's the post [How to efficiently randomly select array item without repeats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17891173/how-to-efficiently-randomly-select-array-item-without-repeats)

thanks in advance for the help .

```
function randomNoRepeats(array) {
  var copy = array.slice(0);
  return function() {
    if (copy.length < 1) { copy = array.slice(0); }
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * copy.length);
    var item = copy[index];
    copy.splice(index, 1);
    return item;
  };
}

var chooser = randomNoRepeats(['Foo', 'Bar', 'Gah']);
chooser(); // => "Bar"
chooser(); // => "Foo"
chooser(); // => "Gah"
chooser(); // => "Foo" -- only repeats once all items are exhausted.
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? How `chooser` is able to retain `copy`?

Comment: calling the `randomNoRepeats`, returns you a new function that can then be called, as long as that function is alive `array` & `copy` are alive in the closure. The most interesting that can happen (after all words have past once), that if the `array` sent in changes (as it is a reference), that the function will also adapt to those changes upon the next reset ^_^

Comment: The inner function is [known as a `closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) and it "closes" around the outer lexical variables and takes them with it when it's returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of `[closures]` in JavaScript.

> According to MDN, functions in JavaScript form closures. A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared. This environment consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the time the closure was created.

In your case, `chooser` is a reference to an instance of the function which is returned inside the function `randomNoRepeats` when the latter is called. The instance of this returned function maintains a reference to its lexical environment, within which the variable `copy` exists. For this reason, when `chooser` is invoked, the variable `copy` remains available for use.

Read more about closures from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures#Closure).

Comment: alright thank you i get it now , it's always the context's fault

Comment: i did that just after i read your answer, but since i created the account yesterday, my upvote is recorded until i get 15 reputation points

Comment: @soufianeyakoubi Thank you :)